# How to have generic numeric type in scala for addition and multiplication?

Tags: scala, typeclass

I'm trying to implement generic numbers in scala that support addition and multiplication, can pattern match to any number and aren't restricted to any one type like `Int`, `Double`, etc. I looked up the docs and found that `java.lang.Number` fits the last criteria, i.e, any number pattern matched against `java.lang.Number` passes. So I quickly wrote up this implementation:

```
case class Number(num: java.lang.Number) {
  def +(that: Number) = Number(this.num + that.num)
  def *(that: Number) = Number(this.num * that.num)
}
```

However, as it turns out, `java.lang.Number` does not have the methods `+` and `*`. So I'm not sure how to implement this now. A professor suggested looking into typeclasses and the spire library, but I'm still having trouble.

Ideally, what I would like to have would be something like this

```
Number[A] + Number[A] returns Number[A]
Number[A] + Number[B] return Number[Finest type containing both A and B]
```

I'd be much obliged if someone could help me out with this. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala has a typeclass for this called [Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) with implementations for the usual JVM number types.

*note:* it doesn't satisfy the `Number[A] + Number[B]` scenario

---

**Examples Below**

If you want to define your own number type, e.g.

```
case class RationalNumber(numerator: Int, denominator: Int)
```

Then you would also implement a `Numeric` instance for it

```
object RationalNumeric extends Numeric[RationalNumber] {
  // implement the abstract methods
}
```

Some scala library methods (e.g. List's sum: `def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B`) take an implicit Numeric instance, so if you introduce an implicit reference to `RationalNumeric`, you could do something like:

```
List(RationalNumber(1,2), RationalNumber(2,3)).sum
```

Also, `Numeric` defines an implicit upgrade that adds operators to its class, so you could do this:

```
import RationalNumeric._
val sum = RationalNumber(1,2) + RationalNumber(2,3)
```

Comment: If A and B are "standard" numeric types then Numeric satisfies Numeric[A] + Numeric[B]. E.g.:  

`def sum[A : Numeric](a1: A, a2: A): A = implicitly[Numeric[A]].plus(a1, a2)`. Usage example: `sum(3, 6.7) // = 9.7, where 3 is Int and 6.7 is Double`.

Playing with implicits you could also provide your own conversion from B to A.